# Cannot install Azure CLI with hombrew on my MAC running on organization proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, homebrew, azure-cli

I have been trying to install azure CLI with homebrew on my mac which is running on my organization proxy. somewhere the proxy is not letting my CURL command to execute. and getting response as below.

tk0991@INHYIMAC0017 ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300736 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Below is the other command and the response to the command that I have tried to install homebrew.

tk0991@INHYIMAC0017 ~ % curl -x http://tk0991:Password0x4001@sub.proxy.att.com:8080 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HomeBrew/install/HEAD/install.sh
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

How can I overcome this problem and can install homebrew and azure cli. hope I get some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, its pretty clear that your organization's proxy is blocking the connection to home brew installation shell script path. Please follow the below action plans and check if that helps:

**Plan 1:**
If you have a VPN, you could leverage that to bypass the proxy and then try to install it by running your above curl command.

**Plan 2:**
[This Homebrew article](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#using-homebrew-behind-a-proxy) mentions about configuring the proxy environment variables. Check if setting that helps.

**Plan 3:**
If the above action plans doesn't help, you could try to [download the](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh) `install.sh` script from a different machine (which is not behind the proxy) and move it to your concerned machine and then grant it executable permissions by running the `chmod +x install.sh` command and then run the installation script as shown below:

```
./install.sh
```

**Plan 4:**
For troubleshooting the Azure CLI installation issue on Homebrew behind a proxy, then you need to remember that the Homebrew also requires the proxy to be configured to get the right resources. The details are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos#proxy-blocks-connection).

**Plan 5:** If none of the above plan helps, you can try checking internally with your organizational proxy team to see if they can allow / whitelist the homebrew endpoints on the proxy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks it plan 3 worked till installing homebrew, Then I tried installing Azure CLI and updating brew using command "brew update && brew install azure-cli" and I am getting as below comment

Comment: Error: Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json!
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300756 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Comment: It worked when I disable VPN

Answer (score 0):

[Homebrew Artcle](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#using-homebrew-behind-a-proxy)

For mac running zsh, open a terminal window,

```
$ vi ~/.zprofile
export http_proxy=http://$HOST:$PORT
export https_proxy=http://$HOST:$PORT
```

Save the file and run the following command to apply the above updates to the current terminal,

```
$ source ~/.zprofile
```

Now install something using homebrew to test the proxy

```
$ brew install node
```